# i am not able to install flash plugin in firefox and chromium

Tags: flash, sudo

youtbe videos are not playing on my system. system asks me to install latest flash player. and when i do so, i am getting the response  "unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted"

the command i am giving is " sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer"

i am working on ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [some programmes are creating this issue](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2065472). Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and issue the following (replace `user` with your user name):

```
sudo chown -R user:user /home/user/.*
```

And then try installing the flash plugin again:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: upvote for `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` not for the first command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Type chrome://plugins in the address bar
- Click on details
- Look for Adobe Flash Player connector
- Deactivate PPAPI
- Close/open chrome and check it

HTH :)